# How to programmatically set the layout_align_parent_right attribute of a Button in Relative Layout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-layoutparams

I have a relative layout which I am creating programmatically:

```
 RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout( this );
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Now I have two buttons which I want to add in this relative layout. But the problem is both buttons are being shown on the left of the RelatiiveLayout overlapping on each other.

```
buttonContainer.addView(btn1);
buttonContainer.addView(btn2);
```

Now I want to know how can I programmatically set the the `android:layout_alignParentRight="true`"
or  `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn"` attribute of buttons as we do in the xml?

Answer (score 667, accepted):

You can access any `LayoutParams` from code using `View.getLayoutParams`. You just have to be very aware of what `LayoutParams` your accessing. This is normally achieved by checking the containing `ViewGroup` if it has a `LayoutParams` inner child then that's the one you should use. In your case it's `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. You'll be using [`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams#addRule(int verb)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule(int)) and [`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams#addRule(int verb, int anchor)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule(int%2C%20int))

You can get to it via code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.id_to_be_left_of);

button.setLayoutParams(params); //causes layout update
```

Comment: what if the anchor has no id? params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.id_to_be_left_of);TextView tvUserName = new TextView(act);

Comment: how about adding the ID?

Comment: What if `button` is on a `RecycleView`? Isn't it a problem adding same or opposite rules to the same widget?

Comment: Its working only for once, if I change alignment its not getting updated. May I know what can be the issue ??

Comment: I tried using that but it  goes red in my code for `addRule` ?

Comment: Sorry i down voted, that was an accident and I discovered it 2 weeks later...

Answer (score 15):

For adding a `RelativeLayout` attribute whose value is true or false use `0` for false and `RelativeLayout.TRUE` for true:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams()
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE)
```

It doesn't matter whether or not the attribute was already added, you still use `addRule(verb, subject)` to enable/disable it. However, post-API 17 you can use `removeRule(verb)` which is just a shortcut for `addRule(verb, 0)`.

Answer (score 13):

1. you need to create and id for the
   buttons you need to refference:
   `btn1.setId(1);`
2. you can use the params variable to
   add parameters to your layout, i
   think the method is `addRule()`, check
   out the android java docs for this
   `LayoutParams` object.

Comment: I would highly appreciate any piece of code. I dont find any method in button.

Comment: Setting id doesn't help since it's expecting a real resource id instead of just a number since setId is being annotated with @IdRes.

Comment: that's new then, in the past you could take a resource number from layouts for example and use it as a base for resource id that will not collide.i guess google must have blocked that/

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin version:**

Use these extensions with **infix functions** that simplify later calls

```
infix fun View.below(view: View) {
    (this.layoutParams as? RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)?.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, view.id)
}

infix fun View.leftOf(view: View) {
    (this.layoutParams as? RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)?.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, view.id)
}

infix fun View.alightParentRightIs(aligned: Boolean) {
    val layoutParams = this.layoutParams as? RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
    if (aligned) {
        (this.layoutParams as? RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)?.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT)
    } else {
        (this.layoutParams as? RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)?.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0)
    }
    this.layoutParams = layoutParams
}
```

Then use them as infix functions calls:

```
view1 below view2
view1 leftOf view2
view1 alightParentRightIs true
```

Or you can use them as normal functions:

```
view1.below(view2)
view1.leftOf(view2)
view1.alightParentRightIs(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Kotlin:**

val params = mBinding.tvTotalAmount.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END)

mBinding.tvTotalAmount.layoutParams = params