# Null Pointer Exception when setting LayoutParams

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, imagebutton, layoutparams

I created button in activity programmaticaly, not in xml file. Then I wanted to set it LayoutParams like in this link: [How to programmatically set the layout_align_parent_right attribute of a Button in Relative Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638832/how-to-programmatically-set-the-layout-align-parent-right-attribute-of-a-button)

But when I tried to launch, I had an exception.

Here is my code:

```
RelativeLayout ll2 = new RelativeLayout(this);
    //ll2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    ImageButton go = new ImageButton(this);
    go.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
    go.setClickable(true);
    go.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.go);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)go.getLayoutParams();
    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT); // LogCat said I have Null Pointer Exception in this line
    go.setLayoutParams(params1);
    go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i3 = new Intent(RecipesActivity.this, MedicineActivity.class);
            i3.putExtra(ShowRecipe, v.getId());
            i3.putExtra("Activity", "RecipesActivity");
            RecipesActivity.this.startActivity(i3);
        }
    });
    ll2.addView(go);
```

Why my app throws an exception? Thanks.

Comment: Probably the line above the line LogCat pointed as null pointer is coming null but to help you it's better you update your question posting the error.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Change this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)go.getLayoutParams();
params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
go.setLayoutParams(params1);
```

for:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
go.setLayoutParams(params1);
```

When you create a View programatically it doesn't have any LayoutParams, that's why you are getting NullPointerException. If you inflate the view from XML, the view is coming now with LayoutParams.

Comment: `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` need to be set as `RelativeLayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`, since there are multiple types of `LayoutParams`

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, it looks like

```
go.getLayoutParams()
```

returns `null` in this line

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)go.getLayoutParams();
```

because you have no `LayoutParams` set for it. This will obviously make `params1` `null` so you get `NPE` here

```
 params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
```

when you try to run a method on it (`addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT)`)

`getLayoutParams()` is for a `View` that has `params` already set. So you will need to set them for `go` before trying to `get` them to use for another `View`

Answer (score 1):

> This method may return null if this View is not attached to a parent ViewGroup or {@link #setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)} was not invoked successfully. When a View is attached to a parent ViewGroup, this method must not return null.

According to the annotation of `getLayoutParams()` in the View.java, your ImageButton is created programly and is not attached to a parent ViewGroup when you call the method, so it returns null.