# Is it possible to modify xml in java programatically. specifically layout_alignBottom, layout_alignLeft and layout_alignStart

Tags: java, android, xml

A few ImageViews have been already created in xml
eg:

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/blue_dot1"
        android:src="@drawable/checkers_blue1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/y1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/x1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/x1"/>
```

Is it possible to update the xml later on programatically in Java for the alignbottom, left and start variables (so that the blue_dot1 image can be moved along the x/y grid of images)

For example  I am going to make a method which has a X and Y arg to allow movement in a simple grid, its just the xml part i cant figure out.

Comment: No, you can't modify layouts programmatically. As well as you can't touch any other app resource.

Answer (score 1):

yes this is very much possible. but you are not modifying the XML instead you are modifying properties of a specific view:

check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4639012/1529129)

> ```
> RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
> params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
> params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.id_to_be_left_of);
>
> button.setLayoutParams(params); //causes layout update
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the xml-file. But you can set LayoutParams of your view programatically.

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
    params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, modifying the XML is not possible to do from Java code. However, you can modify the Views layout properties programatically even after the XML properties have been declared and the view has been drawn. Its fairly simple to do. You just get a reference to that image view:

```
ImageView myImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImg);
myImg.setLayoutParams([Your params here]);
```