# How to programmatically set the layout_align attribute of a Button in Relative Layout?

Tags: android

Here I add one Relative Layout and that layout one imageView and one ImageButton but i want that imageview is align parentRight align parent bottom.

[image]

Comment: You can refer this link.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638832/how-to-programmatically-set-the-layout-align-parent-right-attribute-of-a-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this

```
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

This is the code

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```